# Concurrent Database Access with uWSGI

Tags: python, concurrency, sqlite, multiprocessing, uwsgi

I am trying to find the best solution for concurrent database access with uWSGI.

Some specifics:

I am using python3 (3.3) and sqlite3. I'd like to be able to scale my app up with more processes (and threads too? I'm not sure exactly what --threads does for uWSGI...)

sqlite3 has built in support for concurrent process use, but not necessarily for threads.

So should I write some kind of wrapper around a sqlite3 connection object that implements locking?

Or would it be better to have some kind of worker process that does all DB stuff. If this is the case how could I start this separate worker with uWSGI, and how would I pass messages to web worker processes?

Or is there some better solution?

Finally I have a related question. Should I create a db connection every request, or should I have a persistant connection for each process that stays open while the worker is alive?

It seems to me like creating a connection on every request could be expensive, but want to make sure that having a persistant connection will not cause problems.

Comment: Why don't you use a framework? They've already worked this stuff out for you.

Comment: What sort of framework? I use web2py for larger projects, but I want to write this one from scratch (in the sense that I don't want all the overhead from web2py, django, etc.) Is there some python database framework that would be suited for this?

Comment: For anyone coming to the question, I used sqlalchemy, and found it amazing and quite up to the task.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, if you decide to implement access to the database through a process worker, have the disadvantage of creating a bottleneck deliberately. In my case I want to work with PostgreSQL, where row level locks are transparently automated. A possible solution could be to create a table and triggers to keep the information access and blocking [here an outline](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Row-Locking-td474.html)